# c#. Не меняется alpha-параметр цвета в Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, color, opacity

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь с помощью c# нарисовать полупрозрачный текст. Пишу следующий код:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(250, 250);
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
clr = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0);
font = new Font("Times New Roman", 70);
gr.DrawString("test", font, new SolidBrush(clr), 0, 0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все удаётся.

Но если установить размер текста 65 или ниже, то прозрачность исчезает. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть у кого идеи почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по проведенным экспериментам и раскопкам в доступных исходниках, ошибка где-то в нативных методах GDI.

Воспроизводится только при получении объекта `Graphics` из `Bitmap` и , возможно (не проверял), других наследников `Image`, при вызове `Graphics.DrawString`. В моем случае граничными размерами шрифта оказались 67+ (прозрачность используется) и 66- (прозрачность игнорируется).

При рисовании линий и других графических примитивов не воспроизводится, независимо от размера, типа заливки и масштабирования. Причем даже если "проблемный" текст и другие примитивы рисуются на одном и том же `Bitmap`.

При использовании объекта `Graphics`, полученного из аргументов события `Control.Paint`, проблемы не наблюдается при любых размерах шрифта.

Точной ответ на вопрос "почему?" видимо можно получить только у авторов, т.к. код нативных методов GDI закрыт.

А вот способ обойти проблему есть, хоть и не очень красивый. Если нужен прозрачный текст именно на `Bitmap`, то нужно сделать следующее:

- Создаем объект `GraphicsPath`
- С помощью метода `GraphicsPath.AddString` пишем текст.
- С помощью метода `Graphics.FillPath` рисуем закрашенный объект `GraphicsPath` на `Bitmap`.

В результате ожидаемая прозрачность сохраняется при любых размерах текста. Подробности работы с объектом `GraphicsPath` с примерами кода есть на MSDN.

Должен предупредить, что размер, который указывается в `GraphicsPath.AddString` не совпадает с размером, который указывается в параметре конструктора `Font`, поэтому размер придется подбирать с учетом новых условий.

В качестве альтернативного способа, можно рисовать прозрачный текст сразу на контроле/форме, если такой вариант применим в вашем случае.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый комментарий! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @ВладимирРатушненко рад что помогло. Вообще в формах много разных тараканов, это еще один в мою копилку, обращайтесь =) Если вас устраивает ответ - отметьте его правильным (галочка под рейтингом ответа). Это поможет другим посетителям понять, что именно вам помогло, особенно если ответов много. Эту галочку всегда можно переставить, если появится более подходящее решение. Более одного вопроса пометить нельзя.